# Added new (partially refactored) code, now getting ClassNotFoundException for a class that never existed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have the following code in the main activity of my app:

```
package com.myself.foo.myapp;

import com.someotherfellow.hisapp.OtherClass;
// more imports here

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Object bar = new OtherClass(blah, this, YetAnotherClass.class);
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I build and launch it (using Eclipse and ADT), the app crashes with an unhandled `ClassNotFoundException`. The logcat tells me the missing class is

`com.myself.foo.myapp.OtherClass`

—which is a nonexistent class. The simple class name is that of a class from the other package, but it is prefixed with my package name. Obviously that class will never be found.

When I hover over the constructor call for `OtherClass` in my code, Eclipse shows the correct class name, with the correct package prefix.

Both packages are present in the same source tree as source files—the respective paths are:

```
~/src/myapp/src/com/myself/foo/myapp/MainActivity.java
~/src/myapp/src/com/someotherfellow/hisapp/OtherClass.java
```

What’s causing this behavior, and how can I fix this?

---

**EDIT:** Just out of curiosity, I’ve refactored the code, moving `OtherClass` to the package where Android tries to locate it. Now I get:

> java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.myself.foo.myapp.OtherClass> has no zero argument constructor

Which is indeed true—the constructor of the `OtherClass` takes three arguments, as supplied in the call.

It looks like for some reason the JVM is calling `new OtherClass()` (with zero arguments), which does not match any known constructor of the class. If `OtherClass` resides in a different package, the JVM tries to find a class named `OtherClass` with a matching constructor signature in the current package. If, however, `OtherClass` is in the same package, the JVM at least picks the correct class, but obviously does not find a matching constructor.

Which begs the question: what is causing the JVM to look for a zero-argument constructor?

Note that `OtherClass` is not an Android component: It does not descend from any classes that are part of the Android framework, and is not referenced anywhere in the Manifest. `OtherClass` is a direct descendant of `Object` and implements a custom Interface.

Comment: Compilation error not coming so class is available during compile time not in run time so can you check in run time class path

Comment: @gatisahu what setting should I look at specifically? Do note that both packages share the same root path (~/src/maypp/src), the issue seems to be that something is changing the qualified class name to a different package than the one which I imported it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I’ve found the error. The app had worked before I imported the new code.

The code I imported is an app that had a mix of UI and functionality in its main activity. `OtherClass` is a stripped-down version of the activity in which I only kept the functionality.

`OtherClass` was originally called `MainActivity`, **same as the main activity of my app.** I renamed it into `OtherClass` using the Refactor functionality in Eclipse.

To my surprise, I found the following in my Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".OtherClass"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Apparently, the two identical class names (except for the package name), in conjunction with the local reference, confused Eclipse and it changed the name in the Manifest (where it should have been left unchanged). That explains why:

- The original message about `com.myself.foo.myapp.OtherClass` missing was because the package here is the default package of the app, as per its Manifest.
- After moving `OtherClass` to ensure it would be found, Android still expected this class to be an Activity, which (like other Android system components) is expected to have a zero argument constructor.

Once I changed the name of the Activity in my Manifest back to `MainActivity`, the error went away.

**Lesson learned:** when two classes in different packages have the same simple name **and** there are local references to these classes, renaming one of them may confuse Eclipse.

**Recommendation:** Commit everything before you refactor. After refactoring, look at the diff and see if the changes are correct. This can potentially save you hours of debugging!